# Was told to use select method of tkinter Checkbutton. It doesn't work. How do I have it chacked if the stored setting is true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to make a GUI for my app, but I have hit a roadblock when trying to make a settings Toplevel. This Toplevel comes with tabs and setting buttons that start at the same state their respective settings are stored as from last settings/defaults.

Here is the exception I am currently getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "KMIU 4\kmiu_dv7.pyw", line 38, in settings
    sett.display(main)
  File "KMIU 4\bk\settings.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.windowsettings(tab2)
  File "KMIU 4\bk\settings.py", line 23, in windowsettings
    if settings['Fullscreen'].get(): fs_butt.select()
AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Here is the bit of code that is causing the issue:

```
def windowsettings(self, tab):
        global settings
        text = Label(tab, text ="sample text")
        text.grid(columnspan = 2)
        fs_butt = Checkbutton(
            tab, 
            text="Fullscreen",
            command=lambda: settings['Fullscreen'].set(not settings['Fullscreen'].get()))
        print(settings)
        fs_butt.grid(row=1)
        if settings['Fullscreen'].get(): fs_butt.select()
```

Comment: I bit more of code might help. Well I also think you need to pass on an `BooleanVar()` as the `variable` for the `fs_butt` and use `your_var_name.set(True)` to select it?

Comment: You appear to be using a ttk checkbutton rather than a tk checkbutton. Is that what you're doing? If so, the error is correct: a ttk checkbutton doesn't have a `select` method. Please provide a complete [mcve], including the imports. This is one of the dangers of using a wildcard import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me in my code with `tk.Checkbutton`, `select()` works, and ive seen some other people having the same issue, not sure whats causing it(maybe your using `ttk.Checkbutton`), but here is a way around:

1. First assign a `BooleanVar()` to your checkbutton:

```
var = BooleanVar()
....
fs_butt = Checkbutton(tab,variable=var,......) #same for ttk.Checkbutton(..) too
```

2. Now to set the value of the variable to `True`, to select, and `False` to deselect:

```
if settings['Fullscreen'].get():
    var.set(True)
```

Or maybe your using `ttk.Checkbutton` which does not have `select()` and `deselect()`

Comment: At the top of my code, I import * from tkinter and tkinter.ttk
How do I make sure I am using the right Checkbutton, and what is the distinction anyway?

Comment: its supposed to be `import tkinter as tk` and then use `tk.Checkbutton` and i think the last statement takes over the first statement and hence your `Checkbutton` is from `ttk` ?

Comment: Oh great refactoring time... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @artificialnonintelligence Also better to use `from tkinter import ttk` and `ttk.Checkbutton`